# show multiple data from database using repeater

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, repeater

Want to show 3 Items from database in one row. With this code repeater shows only 1 Item from database.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptItems" runat="server">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <ul>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">

                                <h2><%# Eval("Title") %></h2>
                                <img src='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Image") %>' width="200" height="200" />
                                <p>ISBN</p>
                                <p><%# Eval("ISBN") %></p>
                                <p>Description</p>
                                <p><%# Eval("Description") %></p>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        </ul>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is css issue. I see that you use the bootstrap style, so move the `<div class="row">` out side of the loop.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptItems" runat="server">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <ul>
                        <div class="row">
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                            <div class="col-md-4">

                                <h2><%# Eval("Title") %></h2>
                                <img src='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Image") %>' width="200" height="200" />
                                <p>ISBN</p>
                                <p><%# Eval("ISBN") %></p>
                                <p>Description</p>
                                <p><%# Eval("Description") %></p>
                            </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        </div>
                        </ul>
                    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: @dongou The idea is to place the "row" div out side of the loop. Is more correct to add it on the header  and the close of the div, on the footer.